Oral tradition after Rav Ashi
The Rambam in the introduction to Mishne Torah counts 40 generations from Moshe Rabeinu to Rav Ashi (compiler of the talmud) in the transmission of the oral law and lists the names of these sages.
My question is, do we have any book or authentic source that writes further the after Rav Ashi, the chain of transmission of the Oral tradition from Rabbi to student, until the time of the achronim or at least the Rishonim?

Related: "Is there an Ashkenazi equivalent to the Rambam's introduction to the MT?"

"Until the time of the achronim" - you mean, until the present?

The letter of Rav Sherira Gaon lists the chain up until his time. After that came his son Rav Hai Gaon, and then came the period of the Rishonim which is very thoroughly documented.
Another fantastic resource is the introduction of the Meiri to Pirkei Avos, which is available at alhatorah.org. He gives the entire chain of transmission from Moshe Rabbeinu until the 13th century CE.

The Mishne Torah also mentions that there were sages (called Geonim) who arose after the sealing of the Talmud, who had comprehended it and whose prowess gained them reputation, who lived and taught in Eretz Yisrael, Babylonia, Spain and France. It doesn't claim that any of them received directly from the Talmudic sages, nor that they were part of the chain of transmission. Do Rav Sherira Gaon, Rav Hai Gaon, or the Meiri, actually state that the post-Talmudic sages that they name were part of the chain of transmission of the Oral tradition, starting from Moshe Rabbeinu?

@TamirEvan that issue is explained in the hakdama to Mishneh Torah

@TamirEvan yes and yes

@N.T. Then, could you please quote in your answer the places where they make such statements. From a cursory reading of Rav Sherira Gaon's letter, and the Meiri's introduction to Pirkei Avos, I don't see it stated that any Talmudic sages passed on ('מסר/ו') to post-Talmudic sages, or that any of the latter received ('קבל/ו') from the former.

@RabbiKaii What issue are you talking about?

@TamirEvan don't just use a word search. It's not hard to find the time period being discussed.

@N.T. O.K., Then it shouldn't be hard for you to quote them in the answer.
